# Flex service in debug

Tags: php, apache-flex, service, flash-builder

I am trying to learn the new services method in flex 4. but i can´t get it work. A test oparation near the service in flash builder 4 works. But when i run the code i get  NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed. Does somebody knows what the problem can be?

Tom

**CODE:**

**PHP**

```
 <?php 

class AuthService {
    public function login($username, $password) {
        return 'ok';
    }
    public function logout() {
        return true;
    }
}

?>
```

**FLEX**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:authservice="services.authservice.*">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                loginResult.token = authService.login(username, password);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="loginResult"/>
        <authservice:AuthService id="authService" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button x="97" y="193" label="Button" id="button" click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:TextInput x="91" y="87" id="username"/>
    <s:TextInput x="97" y="117" id="password"/>
</s:Application
```

>

Answer (score 1):

Checkout your [crossdoamin](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf662b6-7fec.html) settings on the php server side.